# How can I calculate the lift force on an aircraft pulling out of a dive?

Tags: aerodynamics

Any ideas on how this question is answered?

> Consider an aircraft dived [sic] along a path inclined to horizontal,
>   perhaps even a vertical path. The manoeuvre whereby the aircraft
>   recovers from this condition and is restored to level flight is known
>   as a pull-out. Calculate the maximum and minimum theoretical lift
>   force and its geometrical position in terms of the load factor n.

Comment: Um... how simplify is the model they are asking for? The easiest way is to assume the trajectory is circunference, its radius depends on the load factor. The really right way to do it is to consider that the airplane will use the maximum lift of the horizontal control surface.... if this is the direction I can develop further

Comment: This sounds good to me. Thanks.